# Convert arma:vec to NumericVector in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I try to use the quantile function in RcppArmadillo, however, in the tutorial, the output of quantile function is arma::vec (The class of output in R is "matrix" "array").

[quantile function in arma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIuP4.png)

I want to convert it to NumericVector. I have tried with the codes following:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;


// quantile function
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector quantile_f(vec V, vec P) {
  vec Q = quantile(V, P);
  NumericVector Q_output = as<NumericVector>(wrap(Q));
  return (Q_output);
}
```

I followed the [link](https://statisticsglobe.com/convert-vector-from-rcpparmadillo-to-rcpp-r) to do this. But I still get class in R = "matrix" "array".

[Output of my function in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhPGT.png)

Can anyone help with this? Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Please don't post images. Links to the documentation are preferred.)

You don't need to convert it:

#### Code

```
// force return as a vector rather than single column matrix
#define RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec quantile_f(arma::vec V, arma::vec P) {
    return arma::quantile(V, P);
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
quantile_f(rnorm(1000), c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0))
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/73979000/answer.cpp")

> set.seed(123)

> quantile_f(rnorm(1000), c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0))
[1] -2.80977468 -0.62874241  0.00920964  0.66478787  3.24103993
>
```

Internally, of course, the equivalent conversion happens as the Armadillo vectors becomes the C++ variant of an R vector which is our `Rcpp::NumericVector`.  But the existing code is nice enough to automate this for you.

*Edit* One can also explicitly reset the dimension attribute from an n by one matrix to a vector of length one:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector quantile_f2(arma::vec V, arma::vec P) {
    arma::vec v = arma::quantile(V, P);
    Rcpp::NumericVector w = Rcpp::NumericVector(Rcpp::wrap(v));
    w.attr("dim") = static_cast<int>(v.n_elem);
    return w;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the help! For your codes, the output is a matrix. But I want my output to be the class = numeric in R (like R internal function quantile(1:1000, c(0.3, 0.5) ). That's why I want to convert it. Do you know how can I get this output? Thanks!

Comment: That is only because of a specific design decision we made (you could say in error....) a decade ago.  We tried to fix this in RcppArmadillo (without breaking things) so there is a `#define` you can set -- just add `#define RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_ANYVEC_AS_VECTOR` before the `#include` for `RcppArmadillo`.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I  want!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer (click on tick-mark you see as the one who asked) and to upvote it (click on upward-trianle).  I noticed you did not do either with the previous answer by Allan -- it 'pays off' to distribute some karma around StackOverflow that way. Accepting an answer also gives you karma points.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I didn't notice that before.

Comment: No worries.  It's all about _receiving_ and then _giving_ little nudges.

Comment: Yes, this forum is just awesome, my question was always answered very soon.